# Forward git traffic pointed at my server to another server

Tags: git, migration

The situation:

I have a large amount of users using my git server: Server A

I'm moving everything over to server B

I want to make the move over as painless as possible so I want people to still be able to point at Server A until they have a chance to adjust their configs. Is there a way within Server A to automatically forward all the Git traffic to Server B?

Comment: What setup do you use for your server? (ex. gitolite/apache)

Comment: Gitlab behind an Apache Reverse Proxy. This is all on an internal network.

Comment: In this case you could simply change the config on the reverse proxy. `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` need to be adjusted.

Comment: People are connecting over ssh not http, most directly to the computer's name.

Comment: If you can move the standard ssh service to a different port you could use `xinetd`, `netcat` or some simmlar tool to forward the ssh connect to the new server.

Comment: Worked perfectly, post my configuration file below, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First I switched my SSH port to 2022 ala many instructions you can find online then.

Here is the configuration file that I used with xinetd. Where ###.###.###.### is the ip address of the server I'm forwarding to.

```
service git_ssh
 {
         disable = no
         type = UNLISTED
         socket_type = stream
         protocol = tcp
         user = nobody
         wait = no
         redirect = ###.###.###.### 22
         port = 22
 }
```